# Bokeh examples not working (updated

Tags: python, bokeh

I am using version 0.11.1 (Anaconda2) and the example code doesn't work. Below is the output (I tried using IPython and Spyder/IPython)

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
p = figure(title="line", plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p.line(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y=[6, 7, 2, 4, 5])
show(p)
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8baa161d296f> in <module>()
      1 from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
      2 
----> 3 p = figure(title="line", plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
      4 p.line(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y=[6, 7, 2, 4, 5])
      5 

**TypeError: figure() takes no arguments (3 given)**
```

Comment: I think you must have some kind of installation or site-packages problem. There's endless examples basically identical to that that have worked without issue for 2+ years, that part of the API has not changed in a very long time (since `0.6`) SO is not very good for collaborative debugging, I'd encourage you to come by the Bokeh mailing list for more assistance.

Comment: Hi, It looks like an installation problem and I reinstalled Anaconda (IPython and Spyder). When I run the same code through a command line it works perfectly.